# Calculating all 1-off combinations of a set of numbers

Tags: java, combinations

The North Carolina Lottery offers several draw games, two of which are Pick 3 and Pick 4. You pick 3 or 4 digits, respectively, between 0 and 9 (inclusive), and the numbers can repeat (e.g., 9-9-9 is a valid combination). I'll use Pick 3 for this example, because it's easier to work with, but I am trying to make this a generic solution to work with any number of numbers.

One of the features of Pick 3 and Pick 4 is "1-OFF," which means you win a prize if at least one of the numbers drawn are 1 up or 1 down from the numbers you have on your ticket.

For example, let's say you played Pick 3 and you picked 5-5-5 for your numbers. At least one number must be 1-off in order to win (so 5-5-5 does not win any prize, if you played the game this way). Winning combinations would be:

```
1 Number    2 Numbers    3 Numbers
--------    ---------    ---------
4-5-5       4-4-5        4-4-4
5-4-5       5-4-4        6-6-6
5-5-4       4-5-4        4-4-6
6-5-5       6-6-5        4-6-6
5-6-5       5-6-6        4-6-4
5-5-6       6-5-6        6-4-4
            4-5-6        6-6-4
            6-5-4        6-4-6
            6-4-5
            5-6-4
            5-4-6
            4-6-5
```

(I think that's all the combinations, but you get the idea).

The most "efficient" solution I could come up with is to have arrays that define which numbers are altered, and how:

```
int[][] alterations = {
    // 1 digit
    {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1},
    // 2 digits
    {-1, -1, 0}, ...
};
```

And then modify the numbers according to each of the alteration arrays:

```
int[] numbers = {5, 5, 5};
for(int i = 0; i < alterations.length; i++) {
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length);
    for(int j = 0; j < alterations[i].length; j++) {
        // note: this logic does not account for the numbers 0 and 9:
        // 1 down from 0 translates to 9, and 1 up from 9 translates
        // to 0, but you get the gist of how this is supposed to work
        copy[j] += alterations[i][j];
    }
    printArray(copy);
}

...

private static void printArray(int[] a) {
    String x = "";
    for(int i : a)
        x += i + " ";

    System.out.println(x.trim());
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. Has anyone come across something like this and has any better ideas?

Comment: This is just a bounded version of the permutations problem. First, for each digit define what numbers it can be `5 -> {4,6}` for 1-off; that's obviously trivial. Then call something like Guava's [`Lists.cartesianProduct`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List...-) on the result. If you don't want to use a library directly, it's open source...  TL;DR a generic solution is fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for backtracking since constructing the alterations array is quite tedious. In your backtracking algorithm you'd construct your candidates, apply the alteration, and check if the resulting combination is valid, if so then you'd print. I suggest you read Steven Skiena's Algorithms Design Manual Chapter 7 for some background information on backtracking and how it can be done with a combinatorial problem.